# SQL query performance for huge data

Tags: sql-server, performance

I have a query:

```
SELECT c.somecolumn,p.someothercolumn
FROM table1 co
INNER JOIN table2 p(NOLOCK) ON co.COLUMN = p.COLUMN
INNER JOIN table3 c(NOLOCK) ON co.column11 = c.column11
WHERE co.filterColumn = 1
```

Table2 is a junction table and the join between table1 and table2 is on a column without distinct values (that’s the requirement and can't be changed) and hence there are cross joins.

Output of this query results in 180 million records.

Record count:

```
table 1:  2 190 561
table 2:    568 277
table 3:    300 150
```

How to optimize the above query? Execution plan:
[image]

Comment: Can you show execution plan as xml,schema of tables involved and count of records

Comment: need more information to help

Comment: also include which dbms you are using 2008, 2012, 2014 ?

Comment: With table and index definitions we can't help. In the meantime you should read this before you continue littering your database with nolock hints. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: Had to look up 18 crore = 180 million

Comment: Also, use this: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: It will be helpfull,if you can paste execution plan as xml (read Paulbarbin comment) and also provide schema

Comment: Just in case it helps, an indexed view might a something to consider

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you at least have indexes on the columns in the joins that include the columns you're returning (for example, in table2, you should have a non-clustered index that is keyed on "p.COLUMN" and includes "p.someothercolumn".  For table 3, key on c.column11 and include c.somecolumn.  You should have an index on table1.filtercolumn. 
Consider also, that you have to return 180 million rows to the caller, that takes time.  Try just inserting that data into a throwaway table just to keep the network load time out of your equation.

Comment: Hi Paul, I have non-clustered index on filtercolumn included with p.column and p.someothercolumn

Comment: Consider updating statistics.  If you believe the execution plan (and I frequently don't), then the time is all in gathering data from multiple processes.  Sometimes this happens when the job is split up into multiple tasks and one scheduler (CPU) gets the overwhelming majority of the work.  The rest of the cpus finish quickly but sit and wait for one process to finish.  Again, not likely but possible. More likely that the execution plan isn't telling you where the pain is. Another option is to remove one table from the join and see if you get a huge performance difference.

Comment: yes, I tried removing one of the table and it showed drastic difference. But as this is a sort of joining table1, junctiontable and table3, as er requirement, I cant skip one of them

Comment: only skipping to see where the pain point is, then we can try to address the problem.

Comment: Another option is to break the query into two parts.  In your sample code, you have table1 joining to table2 and table3 joining to table1.  Is it really like that or does table3 join to table2 (might be better if we use the actual names or at least aliases of the actual tables).

Answer (score 0):

These could be ideally the indexes that are required:

1. For table1 - filtered index on COLUMN and column11 where co.filterColumn = 1
2. For table2 - Index on COLUMN include someothercolumn
3. For table3 - Index on column11 include somecolumn

Answer (score 0):

```html
SELECT c.somecolumn
    ,tmp.someothercolumn
FROM table1 co
INNER JOIN table3 c(NOLOCK) ON co.column11 = c.column11
            AND co.filterColumn = 1
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP (1) p.SomeOtherColumn
             FROM table2 p(NOLOCK) 
    WHERE p.COLUMN = co.Column) tmp
```